# Help needed evaluating double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The task is to calculate the following double-integral
$$\int\int_R{\sqrt{|y-x^2|}}dA$$ over the given set $R$={$(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2}:-1\leq{x}\leq{1}, 0\leq{y}\leq{2}$}.

I figured out the limits of integration and split the integral such that
$$\int\int_R{\sqrt{|y-x^2|}}dA=\int^{1}_{-1}(\int_{0}^{x^2}(x^2-y)^{\frac{1}{2}}dy)dx+\int_{-1}^{1}(\int_{x^2}^{2}{(y-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}dy)dx=\frac{1}{3}+\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{3}{2}(2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx=...$$and I got stuck.
Maybe the latter integral can be done by some (tedious) trigonometric  substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That latter integral can be tackled by some (hopefully not too tedious!) trigonometric substitution. First I will rescale 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}(2-x^2)^{3/2}dx &= 4\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}}(1-u^2)^{3/2}du,
\end{align}
$$
and then the classic substitution here is $\theta = \sin(u)$, giving
$$
\begin{align}
4\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}} (1-u^2)^{3/2}du &= 4\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (1-\sin^2(\theta))^{3/2}\cos(\theta) d\theta\\ &= 4\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos^{4}(\theta)d\theta
\end{align}.
$$
That last integral is straight forward to integrate but just comment if you want me to expand anything.

**Edit**

Ok that last term. To evaluate that we can use
$$
\begin{align}
\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + \cos 2\theta \right),
\end{align}
$$
so to get $\cos^{4}(\theta)$ you just square that again, and then apply the same identity to remove the new square term, which will now involve $\cos 4\theta$, you should be able to go from there?

Comment: Integrating $(\cos\theta)^4$ is not that straightforward...